# How do I do a Contains() in DLINQ with a list of items?

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I want to build a dlinq query that checks to see if a title has any number of items in it. I know you can do `.Contains()` with a list, but I need to check if the title contains any of the items, not if the items contain part of the title. For example: I have three items in the list *"bacon, chicken, pork"*. I need the title of *"chicken house"* to match.

```
   var results = (from l in db.Sites
   where list.Contains(l.site_title)
   select l.ToBusiness(l.SiteReviews)).ToList();
```

If I try the first 2 answers, I get an error `"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."`

The third solution gives me

> Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL."

Comment: i dont think its called dlinq any more.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just say it so people realize I am using a datacontext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Thanks to my good buddy Cory for the help. There are two ways you can do it.

```
var resultSets = (from k in list
                  select (from b in db.Sites
                          where b.site_title.Contains(k)
                          select b.ToBusiness()).ToList<Business>()).ToList();

 List<Business> all = new List<Business>();

 for (int i = 0; i < resultSets.Count; ++i)
 {
     all.AddRange(resultSets[i]);
 }
```

This is a linq query that will successfuly do what is stated. As well, you can also just build the sql query in plain text by hand.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.  You can use a combination of Where and Any to search for substring matches.

```
var results = (from l in db.Sites
                where list.Where(x => 0 != x.IndexOf(l)).Any()
                select l.ToBusiness(l.SiteReviews)).ToList();
```

Comment: i love linq .. and it's when u see answers like this (assuming it works) you love it even more!

Comment: @Pure i love LINQ and lambdas :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to dynamically build a query as outlined here:

http://andrewpeters.net/2007/04/24/dynamic-linq-queries-contains-operator/

Comment: This seems like where I want to be. The only problem I have left is that it appears as though QueryExpression.Lambda doesn't exist.

Comment: Well that didn't work either. :(. "Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL."

Comment: Basically, you need to build a lambda expression of the form:

  l => l.site_title == list[0] || l.site_title == list[1] ...